# Page flip effect on iPhone / iPad (for book reader)

Tags: iphone, animation

anyone has an idea how to build the page flip? I've seen it in flash applications and I want the same functionality for our iPad app ... I want to have a flipped corner on the bottom of the pae that you can drag and flip the page :) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use cocos2d framework to do a page flip application (look for [CCPageTurn3D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-alpha/interface_c_c_page_turn3_d.html) for more info).

Both UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp/Down and transition used in cocos2d support views with only one visible page (left or right) at a time.
If you are interested how to make a page flip effect at all (with left and/or right page visible at a time) take a look at this post: [Implementing 2D Page Flip effect on iPhone OS](http://nomtek.com/developers/page-flip-2d/) or this one: [Adding 3rd dimension to the page flip effect on iPhone OS](http://nomtek.com/tips-for-developers/page-flip-3d/).

Comment: The UIKit route would probably be better at the moment.  Cocos2D's built-in CCPageTurn3D and CCTransitionPageTurn classes do not produce as elegant an effect, and require some manual modification in order to make the other side of the turning 'page' be a solid colour.

Answer (score 4):

When you set the transition use

```
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                       forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Here's a example of how you can do a flip book in HTML which works on iPad
http://devaldi.com/zine/NZ_Tourism_2007.php?ro=html,flash&prefer=true

I think it is using one of the libraries found on this page for jQuery flip books:
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment anyone building an app for iOS 5 and above can use UIPageViewController, it's very simple to use.
more info can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html